# Alternative in WPF to 300,000 DrawLine/DrawRectangle calls, WriteableBitmap not an option

Tags: c#, wpf

I am writing visualization software for financial data that roughly resembles a candlestick chart of `~1500` candles.

Currently, this requires me to draw each candle and it's accessory objects with `dc.DrawLine` and `dc.DrawRectangle` calls.

With the candle width set to `1 pixel`, this results in roughly `300,000` drawing calls. This display also needs to update `30-90 times per second`, so this is far too slow. I am also unable to use `WriteableBitmap` because of visual element layering and transparency.

Does anyone have any recommendations or experience with similar projects?

Comment: not sure wpf is the right technology for this. also you might want to rethink your architecture and optimize as much of it first.   also it is not realistic to "update the display" 60-90 times per second.... even with a gaming engine like Unity or Unreal achieving full 60fps frame rate can be challenging at times.  I am not sure how your "display" works but i am almost 100% sure you will have to render only the visible parts and sort of render as the "camera" moves around like video game.

Comment: also i am just speculating since you did not post any code samples.

Comment: Go for OpenGL or DirectX